# Blank space after listview before next element in stacklayout

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, space, stacklayout

There is a stack layout on my XAML page within the scroll view.
In the stack layout, I have one listview and some other stack layouts.
I'm getting extra space between listview and Stack layouts.

XAML Page:

```
  <ScrollView>    
    <StackLayout Spacing="-6">
        <ListView Margin="0" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding List}"
            HasUnevenRows="true">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <cells:SummaryCell />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout  Spacing="20"  Padding="{DynamicResource ItemsLeftRightPadding}">

                <Label
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    Text="{resources:TranslateExtension Text =  closure}"/>

                <StackLayout
                    Spacing="3">
                    <controls:LabelControl
                        BaseText="{resources:TranslateExtension Text =  PONumber}" />
                    <controls:EntryControl  EntryText="{Binding Number}"/>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout Spacing="3">
                    <Label Text="{resources:TranslateExtension Text =  FirstName}"/>
                    <controls:GrayBorderedEntryControl EntryText="{Binding FirstName}" I/>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout  Spacing="3">
                    <Label Text="{resources:TranslateExtension Text =  LastName}"/>
                    <controls:GrayBorderedEntryControl EntryText="{Binding LastName}" IsVisible="True"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>                       

            <StackLayout
                Padding="{DynamicResource SummaryItemsLeftRightPadding}"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <controls:AddSignatureControl
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Path="{Binding Signature}" />
            </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout> 
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: How big is the ListView supposed to be?  Does it always have 1 item?  What if it has 100 items?  If you want it to be a specific height you need to specify that.

Comment: The items in the listview are dynamic. So can't provide the height for listview

Comment: Xamarin can't either.  It allocates space based on what is available in the parent container, which sometimes will leave extra space at the bottom of the ListView.

Comment: If you have a small number of items, such that they always fit on screen, then instead of `ListView`, use a `StackLayout` with a [Bindable Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't recommend using `Listview` inside `scrollview`, as this will lead to problems such as those you encounter.

You can try to use [Bindable Layouts in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts) to achieve this. This way there will be no such problem.

Please refer to the following code:

```
<ScrollView  > 
    <StackLayout Spacing="-6">
        <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
         Orientation="Vertical" >
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" FontSize="30"   />
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout >

           <!--  other code  -->

        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: The recommendation of using a BindableLayout in a scroll view contradicts Microsoft's documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts#:~:text=Bindable%20layouts%20should%20only%20be%20used%20when%20the%20collection%20of%20items%20to%20be%20displayed%20is%20small%2C%20and%20scrolling%20and%20selection%20isn%27t%20required.

(This post is about Xamarin Forms, but it is still relevant for Maui)